# Sterling took another big leg down

Tags: phrases, expressions

Could someone please help me with a phrase or an idiom in this sentence - "When the UK voted for Brexit on 23 June last year, sterling took another big leg down."

I understand the overall message this sentence is conveying but it's the first time I come across the phrase "took another big leg down" so I'm not quite sure what context can be used in. Could someone please explain it to me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Although the reference is clearly made to the "pound sterling", it seems weirdly phrased. When it is only called "sterling", I initially assume it to be about the current price for sterling silver (similar to the gold price, "gold has gone down"), as opposed to the British pound.

Comment: @Flater - "Sterling"  is sometime used to refer to the British pound: https://www.fxstreet.com/news/sterling-another-leg-down-coming-rbc-cm-201703061101 - http://www.nasdaq.com/video/593a74d7e0fa177b0c48db45 - http://www.uabonline.org/en/news/news/sterlingridesoutanothervolatileweekinukpolitics/36732/0

Comment: @Josh: I wasn't trying to argue that it's wrong, just that it sounds weird to my ears :) But good to see evidence of usage, that always helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Leg](http://financial-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Leg) in financial jargon refers to:

> - A prolonged trend in stock market prices, such as a multiple-period bull market; or, an option that is one side of a spread transaction.

Another  big leg down means another big [fall in value](https://it.investing.com/currencies/gbp-usd-chart) for Sterling vs other currencies, mainly vs the US dollar.